# Extjs 6 + Spring Rest : Empty response for 401 error

Tags: java, spring-security, cors, extjs6, spring-rest

When I make CORS request and server returns 401 code in response I can't get any valuable response info (status = 0, responseText is empty).

On extjs side I use rest proxy with overridden method:

```
doRequest : function(request) {
  var me = this,
    requestConfig = request.getConfig();
  requestConfig.cors = true;
  requestConfig.useDefaultXhrHeader = false;
  Ext.Ajax.cors = true;
  Ext.Ajax.useDefaultXhrHeader = false;
  me.callParent([request]);
```

},

In browser(Chrome) I can find that the response has 401 error code and some headers. But when I try to process the response in following method of proxy:

```
processResponse : function(success, operation, request, response) {
  var me = this;
  if (response.status == 401 || response.status == 403) {
    me.handleSecurityError(response);
  } else {
    me.callParent([success, operation, request, response]);
  }
```

},

I got only success = false and empty response.

Also on backend side I have a spring authentication filter: when I throw an authentication exception in the filter I get empty response, but when I return  ResponseEntity with any code from controller I get valuable response.

What will I have to do to get at least an error code?

Answer (score 1):

How do you configure you cors?

most likely `springSecurityFilterChain` is placed before your cors filter, so cors filter is not invoked.

```
@Component
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
public class SimpleCorsFilter implements Filter
```

try to place `@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)` so the cors filter will be invoked before `springSecurityFilterChain`